# Universal Link can't work after app update version(IOS)

Tags: ios

I will Add Universal Link setting in a new version .[Universal Link setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuEfd.png)

It not work when I Update this version. But It work when I ReInstall the APP.
How can I let Universal Link be work when I update this version?

Comment: please describe your question more detail

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please go through posted link before ask any question

Comment: your question leaves open a bunch of questions itself. it is very hard to understand *what* you are trying to ask. please take more care when writing good questions, so you can receive good answers.